# document.getElementById().innerText in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, getelementbyid, innertext

Quick Cross Browser JS question, when setting the value of a textbox:

```
document.getElementById("balanceText").innerText = "111";
```

and

```
document.getElementById("balanceText").value = "111";
```

Both Work grand in IE,

But they will not work in Chrome, FF, Opera or Safari.

Is there an alternate method that will work in these browsers ?

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All else being equal `document.getElementById("balanceText").value = "111";` works fine in every significant* browser that supports JS.

Make sure that you have one, and only one, element with `id="balanceText"` and that it actually has that as its **id** and not just the **name**.

`*` you don't care about NS 4 do you?

Comment: Fwiw (not much), the `value` property works fine in NS 4 (and indeed NS 3 and NS 2). It's just the `document.getElementById` bit that doesn't.

Comment: Furthermore, using `innerText` on text boxes doesn't work in some browsers (Firefox, for example), so should be discouraged.