# Retrieve innerText of hidden element

Tags: javascript, innertext

I'm trying to get an element's `innerText` but Chrome returns an empty string because my element is hidden.

Firefox does not.

Is there a way to retrieve the `innerText` in Chrome even if the element is invisible?

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('div').innerText + ':' + document.querySelector('div').innerHTML);
```

```css
div {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
Hello, I'm <strong>empty!</strong>
</div>
```

Honestly I'm really surprised Chrome behaves like this, is it a bug?

https://jsfiddle.net/r8q2znc4/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You want to use `textContent` for this, as it returns text from hidden elements

```
document.querySelector('div').textContent
```

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) states that

> `TextContent` differs from `innerText` ...
>
> Internet Explorer introduced `node.innerText`.
>   The intention is similar
>   but with the following differences:
>
> While `textContent` gets the content of all elements, including `<script>`
>   and `<style>` elements, `innerText` does not.
>
> **`innerText` is aware of style
>   and will not return the text of hidden elements, whereas `textContent`
>   will.**
>
> As `innerText` is aware of CSS styling, it will trigger a reflow,
>   whereas `textContent` will not.

This is not a Chrome bug, but rather a Firefox bug, `innerText` shouldn't return the content of hidden elements.

Comment: Thanks :) Will accept as soon as possible. But do you know _why_ Chrome would return an empty string for `innerText` of hidden elements? Just out of curiosity. Edit: Saw you edit, thanks again :D

Comment: Note that text `textContent` will also return text contained between `<script>` tags

Comment: Any idea why .innerText works on my jsfiddle here? https://jsfiddle.net/JaredHess/0jm4tq5p/32/ In my HTML tab, I have three hidden p tags (using style="display:none"). I tested this in both Firefox and Chrome and .innerText returns the same text as .textContent in my jsfildde Console. I usually use Firefox, and so when I ran into this, I thought perhaps it was the Firefox bug you mentioned, but now I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score -2):

`innerText` is [not well supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714162/document-getelementbyid-innertext-in-chrome) on all browsers.

Here are the browsers which support well innerText.

[image]
[Screenshoted here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=innertext)

Comment: Looks pretty well supported to me considering your screenshot is entirely green :P